Ошибка в питоне TypeError: topdeep() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
def topdeep(message):
    global info
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, info)

schedule.every().day.at('23:59').do(topdeep())
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)

Есть бот который в определенное время должен выводить info пользователю, я сделал через schedule, но теперь не понимаю как передать в schedule.every().day.at('23:59').do(topdeep()) параметр message. Буду признателен если сможете помочь.
Если что это только отрывок кода, токен и все остальное есть.

дубликаты где-то здесь

Но это не точно
def topdeep(message):
    def inner():
        global info
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, info)
    return inner
schedule.every().day.at('23:59').do(topdeep(message))
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)


Спасибо, но он не видит message..

Вместо message - какое-нибудь значение
